# Apply a function to subsample of 3-dimensional numpy array - variation on np.apply_along_axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of 3D vectors of shape `(n, 3)`, n being quite large, which can be illustrated as follows:

```
vects = [[x_1  y_1  z_1]
         ...
         [x_i  y_i  z_i]
         ...
         [x_n  y_n  z_n]]
```

I then use an existing function computing the divergence of my vectors array according to spatial coordinates `DataSet` at witch the vectors are specified:

`vects_div = algs.divergence(vects, DataSet)`

What is computed actually doesn't really matters, the important point is that my function needs as arguments:

- **a `(n, 3)` shaped numpy array**
- an object describing the spatial coordinates

and is outputting a `(n,)` array of scalars.

*My issue is that I want to apply this function to subsamples of an array of tensors.*

Let me explain.

This time, I have a numpy array of 3D tensors of shape `(n, 3, 3)`, which can be illustrated as follows:

```
tensors = [[[ xx_1  xy_1  xz_1]
            [ yx_1  yy_1  yz_1]
            [ zx_1  zy_1  zz_1]]
          ...
           [[ xx_i  xy_i  xz_i]
            [ yx_i  yy_i  yz_i]
            [ zx_i  zy_i  zz_i]]
          ...
           [[ xx_n  xy_n  xz_n]
            [ yx_n  yy_n  yz_n]
            [ zx_n  zy_n  zz_n]]]
```

I then use the previous function on three vectors arrays subsamples of this tensors array:

```
tensors_x = tensors[:,0,:]
tensors_x = [[xx_1  xy_1  xz_1]
             ...
             [xx_i  xy_i  xz_i]
             ...
             [xx_n  xy_n  xz_n]]

tensors_y = tensors[:,1,:]
tensors_y = [[yx_1  yy_1  yz_1]
             ...
             [yx_i  yy_i  yz_i]
             ...
             [yx_n  yy_n  yz_n]]

tensors_z = tensors[:,2,:]
tensors_z = [[zx_1  zy_1  zz_1]
             ...
             [zx_i  zy_i  zz_i]
             ...
             [zx_n  zy_n  zz_n]]
```

```
tensors_x_div = algs.divergence(tensors_x, DataSet)

tensors_y_div = algs.divergence(tensors_y, DataSet)

tensors_z_div = algs.divergence(tensors_z, DataSet)
```

Which results in three separate arrays of scalars of shape `(n,)`.

Finally I rebuild the vectors array of results as follows:

```
tensors_div = np.column_stack((tensors_x_div, tensors_y_div, tensors_z_div))
```

All of this can be summarized into a single and dirty line:

```
tensors_div = np.column_stack((algs.divergence(tensors[:,0,:], DataSet), algs.divergence(tensors[:,1,:], DataSet), algs.divergence(tensors[:,2,:], DataSet)))
```

This is all working fine, but I'am looking for a prettier and if possible more efficient way to do it.

I was thinking at the `np.apply_along_axis` function with something like

```
np.apply_along_axis(algs.divergence, 1, tensors, DataSet)
```

But the slices sent to my function are of shape `(3,)` instead of `(n,3)`.

Is there any numpy function which would allow to do what I want ?

Is there a better way than my dirty line ?

Comment: `apply_along_axis`  is not a performance tool.  It is best used when iterating on 2 axes and pass the third to the function - it doesn't improve speed but makes the code prettier.  For your case, the iteration on one axis, while passing the other 2 to the function is fine - provided `algs.divergence` can't be generalized.  That iteration and stack is  not particularly messy.  If you still don't like the looks, hide it in a your own "apply" function!

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj, since I was mostly looking for better performances, I will stick to what I did as of now.